LaTeXTools in sublime text can't find latexmk and all
I just bought a new computer that comes with System76 os POP!_os. Everything was going fine when reinstalling the apps that I need until I installed sublime text and tried to make it compile latex...
So, here's the deal. I've install LaTeXTools via the Package Control. I followed all the steps that I followed to install it on my previous computer. But, somehow, sublime text can't see where are my latexmk, pdflatex, etc. After performing a Check System on LaTeXTools, latexmk, pdflatex, etc. are missing. Here is a screenshot of the result from the Check System command:

In the User Settings, the file contains the following lines for the path for the latex related command:

After comparing the same file on my previous computer, this section of the User Settings file is exactly the same on both computers (old and new).
I searched the net and try multiple things. For instance, the radical ones I tried: reinstalling sublime text, fresh installation of POP!_os.
After a whole 5hours+ of looking for a solution, I gave up and I ask if a user can help me figuring what's going on...
Thank you!

I faced a similar issue. I solved it by making sure I was calling the right latex.
Can you check if you have the correct path for latex in your $PATH and in latextools?
if you type
which pdflatex

You should see where pdflatex if found, and that same path should be in your latextools.
